# Is there a way to print enum values?

Tags: enums, rust

Is there an easy way to format and print enum values? I expected that they'd have a default implementation of `std::fmt::Display`, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

```
enum Suit {
    Heart,
    Diamond,
    Spade,
    Club
}

fn main() {
    let s: Suit = Suit::Heart;
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

Desired output: `Heart`

Error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Suit: std::fmt::Display` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:10:20
   |
10 |     println!("{}", s);
   |                    ^ the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `Suit`
   |
   = note: `Suit` cannot be formatted with the default formatter; try using `:?` instead if you are using a format string
   = note: required by `std::fmt::Display::fmt`
```

Comment: I wrote a crate for this exact problem: https://crates.io/crates/enum-display

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You can derive an implementation of `std::format::Debug`:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Suit {
    Heart,
    Diamond,
    Spade,
    Club
}

fn main() {
    let s = Suit::Heart;
    println!("{:?}", s);
}
```

It is not possible to derive `Display` because `Display` is aimed at displaying to humans and the compiler cannot automatically decide what is an appropriate style for that case. `Debug` is intended for programmers, so an internals-exposing view can be automatically generated.

Comment: This is not the answer

Comment: For enum's with values appended, e.g. `Heart(u8)`, where u8 could be the card number from ace = 1, 2 to 13 (10, J, Q, K); is it possible to output only the enum name, not the value; `Heart` instead of `Heart(7)`?

Comment: The OP asked for "an easy way to format and print enum values".   This is the easiest of all the answers, and it format's and print's..   Answer is correct for OP.

Answer (score 95):

The `Debug` trait prints out the name of the `Enum`variant.

If you need to format the output, you can implement `Display` for your `Enum` like so:

```
use std::fmt;

enum Suit {
    Heart,
    Diamond,
    Spade,
    Club
}

impl fmt::Display for Suit {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
       match self {
           Suit::Heart => write!(f, "♥"),
           Suit::Diamond => write!(f, "♦"),
           Suit::Spade => write!(f, "♠"),
           Suit::Club => write!(f, "♣"),
       }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let heart = Suit::Heart;
    println!("{}", heart);
}
```

Comment: Why when I try to write like this, it always print the first one `♥`.

`Heart => write!(f, "♥")`
`Diamond => write!(f, "♦")`

Comment: To print ♦ you need to create a reference to `Suit::Diamond` and then print it. For instance `let diamond = Suit::Diamond; println!("{}", diamond);`

Comment: What is the need of dereferencing `self` in your answer?

Comment: Nice catch, it is not needed!

Answer (score 28):

If you want to auto-generate `Display` implementations for enum variants you might want to use the [strum](https://docs.rs/strum) crate:

```rust
#[derive(strum_macros::Display)]
enum Suit {
    Heart,
    Diamond,
    Spade,
    Club,
}

fn main() {
    let s: Suit = Suit::Heart;
    println!("{}", s); // Prints "Heart"
}
```

Comment: While it doesn't have many votes (currently), this is probably what you want as it's the least work  to provide simple Display support to any enum.

Answer (score 7):

Combining both [DK.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28024504/1078623) and [Matilda Smeds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45893535/1078623) answers for a slightly cleaner version:

```
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Suit {
    Heart,
    Diamond,
    Spade,
    Club
}

impl fmt::Display for Suit {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
       write!(f, "{:?}", self)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let heart = Suit::Heart;
    println!("{}", heart);
}
```

Comment: I do not understand... if using derive(Debug) why use fmt::Display than ?

It would be the same as:
```#[derive(Debug)]
enum Suit {
    Heart
}

fn main() {
    let heart = Suit::Heart;
    println!("{:?}", heart);
}
```

which defeats the whole purpose of trying to make a Display.

Comment: I am suggesting an implementation of `std::fmt::Display`, exactly because that is what is usually expected in most contexts.

Answer (score 3):

you need to use "{:#?}" for format.
This will work now.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Suit {
    Heart,
    Diamond,
    Spade,
    Club
}

fn main() {
    let s: Suit = Suit::Heart;
    println!("{:#?}", s); 
}
```